# How to get the preferred size of NSButton?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbutton, nsattributedstring

I have a custom view for an `NSMenuItem` that contains an `NSButton`. The title of the button is determined at runtime and I'd like to adjust the frame of the button so that the content (button title) always fits.

I'm aware of `[NSAttributedString boundingRectWithSize:options:]`, but I'm wondering if there's a built-in way to do this for NSButtons or even on the NSView level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSButton` inherits `NSControl`'s [`-sizeToFit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/sizeToFit) method, which may provide what you're looking for.

Comment: And again the NSGod has saved me! Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work with all button types (e.g. checkboxes return a too small size).